# Numeric keyboard as default, but allow text

Tags: android, html, cordova, keyboard, html-input

I'm currently developing an application targeted at android and desktop devices using apache cordova and HTML5.

In order to get the numeric keyboard to pop up I've used `input type="number"`, which works fine.

However, the input field should also accept `strings`. The current functionality of `type=number` is that the ui seems to allow for strings to be entered, but the value property of the element is not changed if the input is invalid (e.g not numberic).

**Is there a way of getting the numberic keyboard on mobile devices, while still being able to enter text?**

My inital tries consisted of capturing the keydown event and manually setting the `this.value` property. I've tried this using jQuerys `.val()` and of course the more 'native' approach `element.val += char`. None of which work. UI is updated, but the change is not reflected in the model.

**EDIT**

For the next guy trying to achieve this.

*1)* The HTML solution.

As @LuudJacobs mentions in the comments below; *There's currently no way to decide which keyboard is shown except for defining the type-attribute.* Though some devices have a button to go back to alphabet keyboard, its not the case for every device. And can not be used reliably.

*2)* Writing a phonegap/cordova plugin.

It is possible to write a plugin to show and hide the keyboard at will. But, as far as I could find, there is currently no way of programmatically telling it to default to the symbols keyboard. Thus the functionality achieved is similar to using `type=number` and `type=text` in the HTML. Another problem with this approach is the diversity of keyboard for android devices, where even users themselves can install their custom keyboard. The functionality of the keyboard can are therefore unknown. What works on one device, may not work on the next.

*3)* JS/HTML/Canvas solution

Finally... A feasible solution. I suggest taking a look at [this walkthrough](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery--net-5774) as it shows an easy way to creating the keyboard using just html and js. Another option would be to use a canvas, and draw the keyboard yourself, but I would imagine that this is more error prone and harder to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29) you can *not* have anything but valid floats in a `input type="number"`. So You can not. On a sidenote: how would users enter text when they'd only have a numeric keyboard?

Comment: Using `type=number` is not a necessity, the desired functionality is simply that the keyboard popup with the numbers/symbols as default. 
On my tablet you can change to the ordinary keyboard even though the type property is set to number. Though this may (should??) not work on other devices.

Comment: I've just tested it on my phone, and it did not work on that. So `type=number` is pretty much out of the picture at this point. As I need both digits and letters, but would prefer to have the digits/symbols keyboard shown as default.

Comment: There's currently no way to decide which keyboard is shown except for defining the `type`-attribute. Maybe you can add a html/js numpad to the site to aid your users?

Comment: The html/js solution is something I will have to consider at this point.

Comment: @LuudJacobs, "how would users enter text when they'd only have a numeric keyboard?" +1